# Prevent Mail app from opening automatically

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

how can I stop the OSX Mail app from opening periodically? I am not talking about startup, I mean when the system is running. If I do not quit the mail app it will be coming to front on a regular basis. It sometimes even opens when I have another program/app in full screen mode and divides the screen to also open in fullscreen...

How do I run the mail app minimised without itself opening all the time?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Are you saying that Mail opens by itself and also takes control of your screen without interaction from you?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that is what is happening. Not when I quit the app, but I want it to run in the background, so I get the notification if a new message arrives.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin for the link. Sadly it is only a workaround

Comment: I think the 'real' workaround is to not use fullscreen.

Comment: well that workaround would be even worse :D though it still opens when I am not in full screen mode