# Mail app randomly opens in split-view full screen while using other apps

Tags: mail.app, email, mojave, fullscreen, split-view

I know this issue is well known, I just wanted to know whether there is a real fix for this issue and not just a workaround.

- Minimizing the mail window didn't work.
- Unchecking "Prefer opening messages in split view when in full screen" in mail preferences didn't work.
- Reconfiguring the gmail account in the System Preferences didn't work.

BTW, one of the causes for this behaviour is when the mail client can't connect to the mail server of one of my emails so it's not only related to gmail.

Again, I know this issue was asked repeatedly but there was no real solution to the problem.

I found a temporarily workaround for now,  I had to literally keep mac mail open in full screen in a different space just to stop its annoyance but I don't like seeing it there all the time when I switch between screens.

I have checked the following questions but none of them helped.
[Question 1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361383/mail-app-opens-randomly-in-macos-10-14-5) [Question 2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368215/how-to-investigate-mail-apps-random-popup-bug-on-mojave) [Question 3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367167/prevent-mail-app-from-opening-automatically) [Question 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344223/mail-app-keeps-popping-up-in-the-background-in-mac-os-mojave) [Question 5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352044/mail-opens-a-window-randomly-in-split-screen-with-my-fullscreen-window)

Note, I'm using macOS Mojave (10.14.6), if upgrading to Catalina would solve the issue please let me know. Although I don't want to upgrade I will do it anyway to get rid of this issue.

Comment: "The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. " https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Although I came here to find the "Right" answer since the other questions didn't contain a real solution. It's weird that it looks like no one actually read my question. Not to mention that I'm aware of the question that you said it was duplicate of mine and I wrote what was their solution which I consider a workaround.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions